# Materialized View having UNKNOWN staleness - Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I am working on Oracle 11G.
One of my Materialized view has become UNKNOWN  (MY_MAT_VW1). You can check the output of the ALL_MVIEWS below.

```
OWNER | MVIEW_NAME | CONTAINER_NAME | QUERY    | QUERY_LEN   | UPDATABLE | UPDATE_LOG | MASTER_ROLLBACK_SEG | MASTER_LINK | REWRITE_ENABLED | REWRITE_CAPABILITY | REFRESH_MODE     | REFRESH_METHOD     | BUILD_MODE   | FAST_REFRESHABLE | LAST_REFRESH_TYPE  | LAST_REFRESH_DATE | STALENESS       |  AFTER_FAST_REFRESH | UNKNOWN_PREBUILT  | UNKNOWN_PLSQL_FUNC   | UNKNOWN_EXTERNAL_TABLE  |  UNKNOWN_CONSIDER_FRESH | UNKNOWN_IMPORT | UNKNOWN_TRUSTED_FD   | COMPILE_STATE  | USE_NO_INDEX  | STALE_SINCE | NUM_PCT_TABLES | NUM_FRESH_PCT_REGIONS | NUM_STALE_PCT_REGIONS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY_DB | MY_MAT_VW1 | MY_MAT_VW1     | select.. | 6728        | N         |            |                     |             | N               | GENERAL            | DEMAND           | COMPLETE           | IMMEDIATE    | NO               | COMPLETE           | 14-Nov-16         | UNKNOWN         |  NA                 | N                 | Y                    | N                       |  N                      | N              | N                    | VALID          | N             | 0           |                |                       | 
MY_DB | MY_MAT_VW2 | MY_MAT_VW2     | select.. | 7074        | N         |            |                     |             | N               | TEXTMATCH          | DEMAND           | COMPLETE           | IMMEDIATE    | NO               | COMPLETE           | 13-Nov-16         | FRESH           |  NA                 | N                 | N                    | N                       |  N                      | N              | N                    | FRESH          | N             | 0           | 0              |                       |
```

The queries for the materialized view contain complex joins between multiple tables, inline views and unions. 
As per my understanding (UNKNOWN_PLSQL_FUNC column) I guess there is a PLSQL Function which is causing the staleness to become UNKNOWN. However I am not sure which one.
I tried re-compiling and refreshing it but no luck.
Can anyone provide me some information on how to detect the root cause and make sure it does not become UNKNOWN again.
Also is there any implication of it on the data stored within it?

Below is just a sample I've created to replicate the scenario.

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITY_T;

ID | ENTITY_TYPE | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |  LEGAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------
1  | INDIVIDUAL  | JOHN       | LESSEN    |
2  | INDIVIDUAL  | ROSAN      | MEL       |
3  | CORP        | SIGMA      |           | SIGMA CORPORATION


--Function to get name base upon type
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NAME (P_ID IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
DETERMINISTIC
AS
LV_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
SELECT CASE ENTITY_TYPE WHEN 'INDIVIDUAL' THEN FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME
                        WHEN 'CORP' THEN LEGAL_NAME
                        ELSE 'NONE'
        END INTO LV_NAME
FROM ENTITY_T
WHERE ID=P_ID;
RETURN LV_NAME;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   RETURN 'NO ID FOUND';
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RETURN 'OTHER ERROR';
END;

--Materialized view creation 
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_MV
AS
SELECT ID,ENTITY_TYPE,GET_NAME(ID) NAME
FROM ENTITY_T;


SELECT MVIEW_NAME,STALENESS,AFTER_FAST_REFRESH,UNKNOWN_PLSQL_FUNC,COMPILE_STATE,STALE_SINCE 
FROM ALL_MVIEWS WHERE MVIEW_NAME='TEST_MV';

MVIEW_NAME | STALENESS | AFTER_FAST_REFRESH | UNKNOWN_PLSQL_FUNC | COMPILE_STATE | STALE_SINCE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST_MV    | UNKNOWN   | NA                 | Y                  | VALID         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle [Issue/Doc ID 757537.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=191500529495929&id=757537.1&displayIndex=4&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=smopletvl_126#CHANGE) mentioned by *JSapkota* states clearly, that this is not a bug, but correct/expected behaviour:

> STALENESS of the mview, refering to PL/SQL function is set to UNKOWN
>   as one cannot determine PL/SQL function changes. Current behaviour is
>   correct as per the design & code.

I guess using [`DETERMINISTIC`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS1918) functions instead of the default scope could prevent it.

Comment: I'll check by making the function DETERMINISTIC and let you know the outcome.

Comment: we currently have some cascading views, but I could not find a custom or non-deterministic PL/SQL function within (other than `wm_concat`, `nvl`, `coalesce` etc.). so the `UNKNOWN`ness state problem may be somewhere else

Comment: `STALE_SINCE` seems to be set for such matviews as soon as there is any change made to any table (or structure) in the database because it is null after a `COMPLETE` refresh

Comment: I am using a function which concatenates the names for a specific entity based upon some rules using CASE statements. The function is causing UNKNOWN staleness. I tried converting function to DETERMINISTIC but no luck.

Comment: Even for UNKNOWN staleness STALE_SINCE column will have NULL value

Comment: we're having this issue when our MV joins to a VIEW that selects from DUAL. I'm not sure why this should impact the ability to determine if the MV is STALE...

Answer (score 1):

As per the My Oracle Support this could be a bug(7582462).

As there is no solution to this bug, you have to deal with fact that staleness will show `unknown`, or not use functions on Materialized View definition.

Reference:[DBA_MVIEWS Shows STALENESS Value of UNKNOWN After Refresh (Doc ID 757537.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=191500529495929&id=757537.1&displayIndex=4&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=smopletvl_126#CHANGE)

Comment: Can there be any data discrepancy for UNKNOWN staleness?

Comment: Mview amy work fine, and refresh raises no issue, but staleness shows `UNKNOWN` status.

Comment: Is it like Oracle does not trust our query output and to be on the safer side it updates Staleness as UNKNOWN.